# How to install and use ARPACK++ on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, lts

How can I install and use ARPACK++ on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? ARPACK++ is an object-oriented version of the ARPACK package. ARPACK is a collection of Fortran77 subroutines designed to solve large scale eigenvalue problems. The package is designed to compute a few eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a general n by n matrix A. I want to install ARPACK++ to perform Molecular Dynamics simulations by running C code in Ubuntu Terminal.

Some relevant websites are:

1. [http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~chico/arpack++/](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/%7Echico/arpack++/)
2. https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/

Comment: Have you checked the details on their website or emailed them for help as their website suggests?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the relevant [packages from Ubuntu *universe* pocket of repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ARPACK&searchon=sourcenames).

At first add universe pocket by

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then install

```
sudo apt-get install libarpack2-dev libparpack2-dev
```

And for C++

```
sudo apt-get install libarpack++2-dev
```

Then you can start developing software using these libraries. Good places to get documentation:

- /usr/share/doc/libarpack2-dev
- /usr/share/doc/libparpack2-dev
- /usr/share/doc/libarpack++2-dev

and official web-sites which are already listed in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please also let me know what syntax should be used to include the libraries in my code? I need to include the libraries like arlssym.h and arlsmat.h. Can you also tell regarding the command that should be used to compile the code?

Comment: Really I'm not familiar with this library. I see that it is packaged for modern Ubuntu. I'm a bit worried by the dates on the web-sites - I see 1998 and 2002, so it may not compile on the modern Ubuntu. You have to specify your use case. For end-users there are many good math-oriented applications like Octave, Scilab; and libraries like SciPy / NumPy for Python, Boost, Armadillo library, etc., and many others listed as dependencies of [*science-mathematics-dev* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/science-mathematics-dev).

Comment: Thank you for your response.